# What is the meaning of & in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What does & indicate in below query? What is the meaning of it?

```
select id, name 
from test 
where num & 1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bitwise and operator.

See the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174965.aspx).

Wikipedia goes into [lots of detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) on bitwise operations.

Logically, the query you give:

```
select id, name 
from test 
where num & 1 = 1;
```

... will only return odd numbers, due to the lower bit in any integer always being 1 when a number is odd.